# Sort a concatenated sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

Consider a sequence based on recurrence relations, `f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)`, starting with `f(1) = x1, f(2) = x2`. For `x1 = 2, x2 = 1`, the sequence begins like this:

```
2  1  3  4  7  11  18  29  47  76  123  199  322  521  843
```

Concatenating this into a string will give:

```
213471118294776123199322521843
```

Now, divide this list into the smallest possible numbers that gives `y(n) > y(n-1)`. Start with the first number, then the second etc. The first output number should always be a single digit. Pad the last number with the required number of zeros.

```
2 13 47 111 829 4776 12319 93225 218430
```

You will get two numbers, `(x1, x2)` as input, on any convenient format, and the challenge is to output the sorted list.

**Rules:**

- Function and programs are OK
- The initial sequence shall have exactly 15 numbers (The last number is `f(15)`).
- `x1` and `x2` are non-negative (zero is possible).
- The output can be on any convenient format
- The output vector `y` must be created so that `y2 > y1`.

  - First the smallest possible `y1`, then the smallest possible `y2`, then `y3` and so on.
- If `x1 = x2 = 0` then output 15 zeros (on the same format as other output, i.e. not `000000000000000`).

**Examples**:

```
Input: 1 1
Output: 1  12  35  81  321  345  589  1442  3337 7610

Input: 3 2
Output: 3  25  71  219  315  0811 3121  23435 55898 145300
                             |
                             Optional leading zero 
Input: 0 0
Output: 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The shortest code in bytes wins. Please include a link to an online interpreter if possible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "smallest possible numbers"? Smallest average? Smallest maximum? Something else?

Comment: @isaacg So as the nth number is greater than (n-1)th.

Comment: The smallest individual numbers. I.e. you can't take the trivial solution with only two numbers: `(2,  13471118294776123199322521843)`. I'll explain it better.

Comment: To clarify my question, what would the proper division of `5467` be? `54 67`? `5 46 70`?

Comment: [Related but slightly different](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47926/sorted-lexical-partition-of-a-number)

Comment: @Sp3000, I haven't seen that one. Yes, that's definitely related.

Comment: @isaacg, if those are the only numbers in the sequence: `5 46 70`.

Comment: How are those the smallest numbers? 67<70. The other question asked for the most separate output numbers, for comparison.

Comment: @isaacg, I've clarified it a bit in the challenge. Find the smallest possible `y1`, then the smallest possible `y2`, then the smallest `y3` that makes `y1 < y2 < y3`. Does it make sense or is it still unclear?

Comment: @nicael, you're right. Fixed!

Comment: Is it fine if my function produces more numbers than shown in your example?

Comment: So the only case when y1 <= y2 <= y3 is when x1 == x2 == 0?

Comment: @edc65, yes it is.

Comment: The 0 thing seems like a rather annoying and unnecessary exception.

Comment: @StewieGriffin That's much better, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth, 56 bytes

```
LsgM.:sMb2?sQsM.WyHX_1Z`0u?yGX_1GHaGHjkhM.u,eNsN14QYmZ15
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=LsgM.%3AsMb2%3FsQsM.WyHX_1Z%600u%3FyGX_1GHaGHjkhM.u%2CeNsN14QYmZ15&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%2C+1%0A1%2C+1%0A3%2C+2%0A0%2C+0&debug=0)

**Explanation:**

First, we check whether the input is precisely `0, 0`. If so, print 15 zeros.

Otherwise, we produce the sequence, with `jkhM.u,eNsN14Q`. This is similar to the standard Pyth algorithm for the Fibonacci sequence.

Next, we reduce over this string. The accumulator is a list of strings, representing each number in the divided sequence. At each reduction step, we take the next character, and check whether the accumulator is in order, using the helper function `y`, defined with `LsgM.:sMb2`, which is truthy iff the input is out of order. If it is in order, we append the next character to the list as its own number. If not, we add the next character to the end of last string. This is accomplished with `u?yGX_1GHaGH ... Y`.

Next, we perform a functional while loop. The loop continues until the running list is in order, reusing the helper function. At each step, a `0` is added to the end of the last string in the list. This is accomplished with `` .WyHX_1Z`0 ``.

Finally, the strings are converted to integers, with `sM`, and printed.

---

## Pyth, 51 bytes

```
LsgM.:sMb2?sQsM.WyHX_1Z`0hf!yT_./jkhM.u,eNsN14QmZ15
```

I believe this works, but it is far too slow to test - it's a brute force solution for dividing the string.

---

I will be making some improvements to the `X` function, but the above code works in the version of Pyth that was most recent when the question was posted.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript ES6, 127 <s>135</s>

```js
(a,b)=>eval("for(n=r=[],v=13,o=a+n+b;v--;a=b,b=t)o+=t=b+a;for(d of o+'0'.repeat(99))(n+=d)>+v&&(r.push(v=n),n='');+v?r:[...o]")
```

**Test**

```js
F=(a,b)=>eval("for(n=r=[],v=13,o=a+n+b;v--;a=b,b=t)o+=t=b+a;for(d of o+'0'.repeat(99))(n+=d)>+v&&(r.push(v=n),n='');+v?r:[...o]")

// less golfed

U=(a,b)=>{
  for(n=r=[], o=a+n+b, v=13; v--; a=b, b=t)
    o+= t= b+a;
  for(d of o+'0'.repeat(99))
    if ((n+=d) > +v)
      r.push(v=n), n='';
  return +v ? r : [...o]
}

function test(){
  var i = I.value.match(/\d+/g)
  O.textContent = i.length > 1 ? F(+i[0],+i[1]) : ''
}
test()
```

```html
A,B : <input id=I value='0 1' oninput='test()'>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: There is an error for x1=0, x2>0, e.g. input "0 1".

Comment: @flornquake fixed. The byte count remains the same, having reduced a little the zero filling code

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript ES6, <s>187</s> <s>180</s> <s>187</s> <s>184</s> <s>182</s> <s>179</s> <s>175</s> <s>172</s> <s>165</s> <s>160</s> <s>155</s> 154 bytes

```
(a,b)=>eval('d=""+a+b;for(i=-12,j=1;++i<99;)i<2?(c=b,d+=b=a+b,a=c,r=a?[d[0]]:"0,".repeat(15)):(f=+d.slice(j,i))>r[r.length-1]?(r.push(f),j=++i-1):d+=0;r')
```

I get similar results when run it for `1,1` and `3,2` test cases. `0,0` has taken an excess 26 bytes...

De-golf + converted to ES5 + demo:

```js
function s(a, b) {
  d = "" + a + b;
  for (i = -12, j = 1; ++i < 99;)
    i < 2 ?
      (c = b, d += b = a + b, a = c, r = a ? [d[0]] : "0,".repeat(15))
    : (f = +d.slice(j, i)) > r[r.length - 1] ?
      (r.push(f), j = ++i - 1)
      : d += 0;
  return r
}
document.write(
   s(1,1)+"<br>"+
   s(3,2)+"<br>"+
   s(0,0)
)
```

Comment: Why does it produce more numbers? And shouldn't it be easy to fix? The requirement is `n <= 15`.

Comment: @Stewie But hey, the first produces 12 and the second 11. That's smaller than 15.

Comment: The initial sequence `f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)` has a max value of exactly 15. The number of output values are determined based on the algorithm, nothing else.

Comment: @Stewie ok, so it must be exactly 15, right? Then, by n<=15 you mean that the input numbers are less than 15?

Comment: The number of values in the initial sequence is 15. The starting values `f(1)=x1` and `f(2)=x2` can be higher than 15. The number of output values is determined based on the input values. For `3 2` it will be 10.

Comment: @nimi that was actually a test condition, trying to figure out what I was going to put there.

Comment: @nimi for now replacing it with 99, because can't find any problem with the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 162 bytes

```js
(a,b)=>(k=[...Array(15).keys(y="")],p=-1,z=k.map(_=>0),a|b?[...k.map(f=n=>n--?n?f(n)+f(n-1):b:a).join``,...z].map(d=>+(y+=d)>p?(p=y,y=" ",p):"").join``:z.join` `)
```

### Explanation

```js
(a,b)=>(
  k=[...Array(15).keys(y="")],     // k = array of numbers 0 to 14, initialise y
  p=-1,                            // initialise p to -1 so that 0 is greater than p
  z=k.map(_=>0),                   // z = array of 15 zeroes
  a|b?[                            // if a and b are not 0
      ...k.map                     // for range 0 to 14
      (f=n=>n--?n?f(n)+f(n-1):b:a) // recursive sequence function (0 indexed)
      .join``,                     // join result of f(0) to f(14) as a string
      ...z                         // append zeroes for padding
    ].map(d=>                      // for each digit of concatenated result
      +(y+=d)                      // append the digit to the current number y
      >p?(                         // if the current number is greater than the previous p
        p=y,                       // set previous to the current number
        y=" ",                     // reset y (with space as a separator)
        p                          // output the current number (with space at the start)
      ):""                         // else add nothing to the output
    )
    .join``                        // return the output as a string
  :z.join` `                       // return a bunch of zeroes if a and b are 0
)
```

### Test

```js
var solution = (a,b)=>(k=[...Array(15).keys(y="")],p=-1,z=k.map(_=>0),a|b?[...k.map(f=n=>n--?n?f(n)+f(n-1):b:a).join``,...z].map(d=>+(y+=d)>p?(p=y,y=" ",p):"").join``:z.join` `)
```

```html
x1 = <input type="number" id="x1" value="3" /><br />
x2 = <input type="number" id="x2" value="2" /><br />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(+x1.value,+x2.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>165</s> <s>159</s> <s>152</s> <s>142</s> 141 bytes

```
w=take 15
x#y=x:scanl(+)y(x#y)
0%0=w[0,0..]
x%y=g(-1)(w(x#y)++0%0>>=show)(-1)
g _""_=[]
g b l@(h:t)a|b>a=b:g 0l b|1<2=g(max 0b*10+read[h])t a
```

Usage example: `3 % 2` -> `[3,25,71,219,315,811,3121,23435,55898,145300]`.

[Online demo](http://goo.gl/3kaQ7x) (with a `main` wrapper).

How it works:

```
w=take 15
x#y=x:scanl(+)y(x#y)              -- fibonacci sequence generator for x and y

0%0=w[0,0..]                      -- special case 0%0
x%y=g(-1)(w(x#y)++0%0>>=show)(-1) -- calculate fib sequence, add some extra 0 and
                                  -- flatten all digits into a single string.
                                  -- start calculating the resulting sequence

g _""_=[]                         -- if we don't have digits left, stop.
                                  -- the final 0 in the second parameter is ignored.
g b l@(h:t)a
  |b>a=b:g 0l b                   -- if the current number is greater than the
                                  -- previous one, take it and start over.
  |1<2=g(max 0b*10+read[h])t a    -- otherwise add the next digit and retry.
                                  -- The "max" fixes the initial call with -1.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 192 bytes

```
f[{0,0}]:=0~Table~15
f@l_:=(t=0;q={};If[#>0,q~Join~{10^⌈Log10[t/#]⌉#},q]&[Last@#]&@FoldList[If[#>t,AppendTo[q,t=#];0,#]&[10#+#2]&,0,Flatten@IntegerDigits@SequenceFoldList[#+#2&,l,Range@13]])
```

Test cases:

```
f[{2, 1}]
(* {2, 13, 47, 111, 829, 4776, 12319, 93225, 218430} *)
f[{3, 2}]
(* {3, 25, 71, 219, 315, 811, 3121, 23435, 55898, 145300} *)
f[{0, 0}]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

The lengths of the function names are killing me.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 61 bytes

```
(|/<':){@[x;t-1;(0^x t)+10*]_t:1+*&~0>':x}/.',/$13{x,+/-2#x}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dci7CoAgFADQXxGKfOe9umlE/xHVZkPg5CBY/bp1xnPpdKbWome3majndVlLyBoDg72QzCWC2I7sUYrhhZn68piRKtOjq0VJo233T4uUIcHgiA1AgLcP)

- `.',/$13{x,+/-2#x}/` builds the sequence, converting it into a list of (integer) digits
- `(|/<':)` is used as the while condition, causing iteration to continue so long as there is any number in the list smaller than its predecessor
- `t:1+*&~0>':x` identifies the index immediately after the first value less than or equal to its predecessor
- `@[x;t-1;(0^x t)+10*]` is used to merge numbers in the list together; e.g. `1 2` becomes `12 2`. Since indexing a list out of bounds returns a null, we zero-fill with `0^`. This handles the last iteration, where we may need to append additional 0's
- `@[...]_t` removes the "leftover" value at index `t` from the left-hand-side list (e.g. `12 2` becomes `12`)

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, <s>167</s> 166 bytes

```
param($x,$w)if($w-lt($x-eq0)){"0`n"*15;exit}[char[]]("$x"+-join(0..13|%{$w;$w=$x+($x=$w)}))|%{$z+="$_";if(+$z-gt$y){($y=$z);$z=""}};if($z){while(+$z-lt$y){$z+="0"}$z}
```

Saved a byte by eliminating the `$s` variable and just feeding the output loop directly.

#### Ungolfed and commented:

```
param($x,$w)           # Take input parameters as x and w
if($w-lt($x-eq0)){     # If x=0, ($x-eq0)=1, so $w-lt1 implies w=0 as well
  "0`n"*15             # Print out 15 0's separated by newlines
  exit                 # And exit program
}                      # otherwise ...
[char[]](              # Construct the sequence string as a char-array
"$x"+-join(            # Starting with x and concatenated with a joined array
  0..13|%{             # Loop
    $w                 # Add on w
    $w=$x+($x=$w)      # Recalculate for next loop iteration
  }
))|%{                  # Feed our sequence as a char-array into a loop
  $z+="$_"             # z is our output number, starts with the first digit
  if(+$z-gt$y){        # If z is bigger than y (initialized to 0)
    ($y=$z)            # Set y equal to z and print it
    $z=""              # Reset z to nothing to start building the next number
  }
}
if($z){                # If there is remaining digits, we need to pad zeroes
  while(+$z-lt$y){     # Until z is bigger than y
    $z+="0"            # Tack on a zero
  }
  $z                   # Print the final number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 107 bytes

```perl6
{$_=@=(|@_,*+*...*)[^15].join.comb;.sum??[.shift,{last if !@$_;until (my$a~=.shift//0)>$^b {};$a}...*]!!$_} # 107
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
# give it a lexical name for ease of use
my &code = {...}

# use ｢eager｣ because the anonymous block returns a lazy array
# and ｢say｣ doesn't ask it to generate the values
say eager code 2, 1;
# [2 13 47 111 829 4776 12319 93225 218430]
say eager code 1, 1;
# [1 12 35 81 321 345 589 1442 3337 7610]
say eager code 3, 2;
# [3 25 71 219 315 0811 3121 23435 55898 145300]
say eager code 0, 0;
# [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
say eager code 0, 1;
# [0 1 12 35 81 321 345 589 1442 3337 7000]
```

#### Explanation

creates a Fibonacci like sequence, starting with the arguments (`@_`) slipped (`|`) in

```perl6
|@_,*+*...*
```

takes the first 15 elements of that sequence

```perl6
(…)[^15]
```

combines that into a single string (`.join`), splits it into a sequence of individual characters (`.comb`) and stores that in the "default" scalar (`$_`) after coercing the sequence into a mutable array, by first storing it in an anonymous array (`@`)

```perl6
$_=@=(…)[^15].join.comb;
```

it finds the sum of the values in the default scalar, and if that is zero returns the default scalar, which will contain an array of 15 zeros

```perl6
.sum?? … !!$_
```

if the sum isn't zero, it creates a list by first shifting off the first element in the default scalar

```perl6
.shift, …
```

followed by generating the rest of the values, checking it against the previous one (`$^b`)
if the default scalar runs out of values, use 0 instead (`//0`)

```perl6
…,{ … ;until (my$a~=.shift//0)>$^b {};$a}...*
```

stopping when there is no elements left in the default scalar

```perl6
…,{last if !@$_; … }...*
```

Comment: why must there be a space in `until (my$a...`? Is `(` not a special delimiter?

Comment: @cat that would be a call to the subroutine named `until`, which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 39 bytes

```
-.ị
ÇSṭƊ13¡DFŒṖḌ<ƝṖẠƊƇḢṪ×⁵ṭƲÇ>/$¿µṁS?15
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19X7@Hubq7D7cEPd6491mVofGihi9vRSQ93Tnu4o8fm2FwQY9eCY13H2h/uWPRw56rD0x81bgUp3XS43U5f5dD@Q0BeY7C9oen///@jjXQMYwE)

This is unbelievably inefficient, both time-wise and memory-wise. You can see it in action for up to \$f(11)\$ on TIO,  but it times out if you include up to \$f(15)\$.  Luckily, the run time does not heavily depend on the input, so is generally constant. However, Python will usually error due to memory restrictions

### How it works

This works by generating all partitions of the digits of the sequence and keeping those which are strictly ascending, ignoring the last element. Due to the way Jelly generates the partitions of a list, this yields the intended array as the first such partition.

```
-.ị - Helper link. Takes an array, A, on the left
-.  - Yield -0.5
  ị - Take the -0.5th element of A, which returns the last 2 elements

ÇSṭƊ13¡DFŒṖḌ<ƝṖẠƊƇḢṪ×⁵ṭƲÇ>/$¿µṁS?15 - Main link. Takes [a,b] on the left
                                ?   - If statement:
                               S    -   Condition: sum (i.e. a ≠ 0, b ≠ 0)
                             µ      -   If:
   Ɗ                                -     Define a monad f(A):
Ç                                   -       Take the last two elements of A
 S                                  -       Take their sum
  ṭ                                 -       Tack the sum to the end of A
    13¡                             -     Repeat f(A) 13 times, starting with A = [a, b]
       D                            -     Convert to digits
        F                           -     Flatten into an array, D
         ŒṖ                         -     Yield all partitions of D
           Ḍ                        -     Convert arrays back to decimals
                Ɗ                   -     Define a monad g(A):
             Ɲ                      -       Over overlapping pairs of A:
            <                       -         Is less than?
              Ṗ                     -       Remove the last
               Ạ                    -       All true?
                 Ƈ                  -     Keep the partitions which are true under g(A)
                  Ḣ                 -     Take the first one, P
                            ¿       -     While loop:
                           $        -       Condition:
                        Ç           -         Last 2 elements of P
                         >/         -         First is greater than the second
                       Ʋ            -       Body:
                   Ṫ                -         Last element of P
                    ×⁵              -         Times 10
                      ṭ             -         Tack to the end of P
                              ṁ  15 -   Else: Repeat to length 15
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><del>53</del></sup> 52 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ü⌐↓├¶cRU!>πf_╙ⁿεd╔╘≥↔IQ┘┼▐↓▒Φ╙ε☺ÉL╚Jö┤Å☺╠╓§j╨áuf░╢A╬
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9aa919c314635255213ee3665fd3fcee64c9d4f21d4951d9c5de19b1e8d3ee01904cc84a94b48f01ccd6156ad0a07566b0b641ce&i=1,1%0A3,2%0A0,0%0A&m=2)

Not too well optimized, can probably be shortened a lot.

However, pretty proud that I managed to make it work for all the testcases.

It uses the X and Y registers to store previous values while comparing them in the loop, then pushes X to stack when the Y is greater than it.